How to validate request with zod in express middleware?
I had to write zod express validator middleware that is slightly modified from zod-express-middleware
This is my custom request validator
export type ErrorListItem = {
  type: 'Query' | 'Params' | 'Body' | 'Response';
  errors: ZodError<any>;
};

type RequestSchemas<TParams, TQuery, TBody, TResponse> = Partial<{
  params: ZodSchema<TParams>;
  query: ZodSchema<TQuery>;
  body: ZodSchema<TBody>;
  response: ZodSchema<TResponse>;
}>;

type RequestCallback<TParams, TQuery, TBody, TResponse> = (
  data: {
    params: TParams;
    body: TBody;
    query: TQuery;
  },
  req: Express.Request,
  res: Express.Response
) => Promise<TResponse>;

type ValidatedRequest = (
  req: Express.Request,
  res: Express.Response,
  next: Express.NextFunction
) => Promise<void>;

export const doValidatedRequest =
  <TParams, TQuery, TBody, TResponse>(
    schemas: RequestSchemas<TParams, TQuery, TBody, TResponse>,
    cb: RequestCallback<TParams, TQuery, TBody, TResponse>,
    succesStatusCode: number = 200
  ): ValidatedRequest =>
  async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      const errors: ErrorListItem[] = [];

      const requestData = {
        params: {} as any,
        body: {} as any,
        query: {} as any
      };

      if (schemas.params) {
        const parsedParams = schemas.params.safeParse(req.params);
        if (parsedParams.success) {
          requestData.params = parsedParams.data;
        } else {
          errors.push({ type: 'Params', errors: parsedParams.error });
        }
      }

      if (schemas.body) {
        const parsedBody = schemas.body.safeParse(req.body);
        if (parsedBody.success) {
          requestData.body = parsedBody.data;
        } else {
          errors.push({ type: 'Body', errors: parsedBody.error });
        }
      }

      if (schemas.query) {
        const parsedQuery = schemas.query.safeParse(req.query);
        if (parsedQuery.success) {
          requestData.query = parsedQuery.data;
        } else {
          errors.push({ type: 'Query', errors: parsedQuery.error });
        }
      }

      if (errors.length) {
        next(errors);
      }

      const response = await cb(requestData, req, res);
      if (schemas.response) {
        const parsedResponse = schemas.response.safeParse(response);
        if (parsedResponse.success) {
          res.status(succesStatusCode).json(parsedResponse.data);
        } else {
          errors.push({ type: 'Response', errors: parsedResponse.error });
        }
      } else {
        // Response not specified and thus not expected
        res.status(succesStatusCode).json(response);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  };

Now when I try to use it
router.get('/', doValidatedRequest({}, async ({}, req, res) => someFunction(req, res));

or
router.get('/:id', doValidatedRequest({
  query: z.object({
    id: z.string()
  }),
}, async ({ query: { id }}) => someFunction(id));

I constantly get the eslint error
Promise returned in function argument where a void return was expected. eslint(@typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises)
It doesn't seem to matter how I define the someFunction
const someFunction = async (): Promise<void> => { // do something }
const someFunction = async (): Promise<string> => { return "OK" }
const someFunction = async (id: string): Promise<string> => { return id }
const someFunction = (): void => { // do something }
const someFunction = (): string => { return "OK" }
const someFunction = (id: string): string => { return id }

Can anyone spot why's that? I can't seem to find the cause for this and I am also wondering is it going to cause any further issues at some point as well. How could I improve this middleware?
The idea is that this could be used to validate the request params and response, if needed, pass the validated and correctly typed parameters to the controller function which then passes the optionally validated response to the validator that then sends the response back to the requester.

There seems to be two problems in my definition and both can be seen in this snippet
type ValidatedRequest = (
  req: Express.Request,
  res: Express.Response,
  next: Express.NextFunction
) => Promise<void>;

export const doValidatedRequest =
  <TParams, TQuery, TBody, TResponse>(
    schemas: RequestSchemas<TParams, TQuery, TBody, TResponse>,
    cb: RequestCallback<TParams, TQuery, TBody, TResponse>,
    succesStatusCode: number = 200
  ): ValidatedRequest =>
  async (req, res, next) => {

First one is that I have typed the return type of ValidatedRequest as Promise<void> and when that is the return type of the doValidatedRequest TS sees that there is a Promise<void> returned. The whole ValidatedRequest type is maybe a bit redundant and the return type for the doValidatedRequest can be just the express.RequestHandler.
Second, I have defined the ValidatedRequest (or RequestHandler) function as async (req, res, next) => ... which also tells TS that there's some kind of promise to be returned.
And then thirdly I guess I have some weird eslint rule telling me that I shouldn't use promises in express middlewares. Not sure, if express can handle those. I guess it can.
Anyways now the fix is to redefine the doValidatedRequest as
export const doValidatedRequest =
  <TParams, TQuery, TBody, TResponse>(
    schemas: RequestSchemas<TParams, TQuery, TBody, TResponse>,
    cb: RequestCallback<TParams, TQuery, TBody, TResponse>,
    succesStatusCode = 200
  ): RequestHandler =>
  (req, res, next) => {
    const errors: ErrorListItem[] = [];

    const requestData = {
      params: {} as any,
      body: {} as any,
      query: {} as any
    };

    if (schemas.params) {
      const parsedParams = schemas.params.safeParse(req.params);
      if (parsedParams.success) {
        requestData.params = parsedParams.data;
      } else {
        errors.push({ type: 'Params', errors: parsedParams.error });
      }
    }

    if (schemas.body) {
      const parsedBody = schemas.body.safeParse(req.body);
      if (parsedBody.success) {
        requestData.body = parsedBody.data;
      } else {
        errors.push({ type: 'Body', errors: parsedBody.error });
      }
    }

    if (schemas.query) {
      const parsedQuery = schemas.query.safeParse(req.query);
      if (parsedQuery.success) {
        requestData.query = parsedQuery.data;
      } else {
        errors.push({ type: 'Query', errors: parsedQuery.error });
      }
    }

    if (errors.length) {
      next(errors);
    }

    cb(requestData, req, res)
      .then(response => {
        if (schemas.response) {
          const parsedResponse = schemas.response.safeParse(response);
          if (parsedResponse.success) {
            res.status(succesStatusCode).json(parsedResponse.data);
          } else {
            errors.push({ type: 'Response', errors: parsedResponse.error });
          }
        } else {
          // Response not specified and thus not expected
          res.status(succesStatusCode).json(response);
        }
      })
      .catch(next);
  };

This should work as well as the original one and there are no any kind of TS/eslint errors shown
